# Write SpringBatch using SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm learning how to write `SpringBatch` using `SpringBoot`.

Example my spring batch looked as below

```
  <batch:job id="job" >
            <batch:step id="deleteFile" next="generateFile">
                <batch:tasklet ref="fileDeleting" />
            </batch:step>
            <batch:step id="generateFile" next="emailFile" >
                <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                    <batch:chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" processor="processor" commit-interval="10" />
                </batch:tasklet>
            </batch:step>
            <batch:step id="emailFile">
                <batch:tasklet ref="emailTasklet" />
            </batch:step> 
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="jobListener" />
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:job>
```

As you can see, before reader get called, `deleteFile` will be called first. Once the `generateFile` done, `emailFile` will get called.

And this is how the `generateFile` looked like when it turn to SpringBoot.

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job job() {

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        System.out.println("In step1");
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<String, String>chunk(1)
                .reader(new Reader())
                .processor(new Processor())
                .writer(new Writer())
                .build();
    }
}
```

How can I involve the `deleteFile` and `emailFile` in `SpringBoot` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare tasklet steps just like item oriented steps, something like:

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .tasklet(deleteFileTasklet())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step2() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                .<String, String>chunk(1)
                .reader(new Reader())
                .processor(new Processor())
                .writer(new Writer())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step3() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step3")
                .tasklet(emailTasklet())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Tasklet deleteFileTasklet() {
        return null; // TODO implement delete file tasklet
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Tasklet emailTasklet() {
        return null; // TODO implement email tasklet
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step1())
                .next(step2())
                .next(step3())
                .build();
    }

}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks sir, it helped. In the `writer`, I want it to write the data to excel file. Do you know where I can get such information ?

Comment: Spring Batch does not provide a writer for MS Excel out of the box. The project I am aware of and which might help is [spring batch extensions](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/tree/master/spring-batch-excel). It adds support for MS Excel but unfortunately provides only a reader. You can still write a custom writer using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org) for instance.